# How to animate diagrams with jQuery and jQplot (updating data)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, diagram, jqplot

I am "animating" diagrams over time by changing the data and redrawing them.

```
// initialization
var data = ...
var targetPlot = $.jqplot('#diagram', data, diagramOptions);
```

Now after some time I will change the data in some way and want to update the diagram. The following solution works:

```
// update Data
targetPlot.data = ...;
// remove old diagram
$('#<%= "diagram" + diagram.id.to_s %>container').empty();
// redraw
targetPlot = $.jqplot('#diagram', data, diagramOptions);
```

Bit this is a complete redraw. With lots of data and a short intervall jQPlot takes much memory and the diagram is flickering.

How to do this correct?

The solution using the redraw-function for me only draws the old diagram:

```
// update Data
targetPlot.data = ...;
targetPlot.redraw();
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the way I found after lots of investigation. I am writing this down to help someone reading this question.

The correct place to update the data is in the series property, after updating the data you can redraw the plot:

```
targetPlot.series[0].data = myData;
targetPlot.redraw();
```

If your axis changed, then you can rescale them by using `replot()` instead of `redraw()`:

```
targetPlot.replot({resetAxes:true});
```

This is much faster than redrawing a new plot every time.

Comment: You can also activate [`animateReplot`](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/barLineAnimated.html) to get a little animation on the replot

Comment: Plus 300 if I could... the comment above is key to reanimating the chart. Thanks.