# Jqplot vs Google chart API

Tags: google-visualization, jqplot

I am looking for a charting library and zeroed in on JQplot the library looks impressive.
however i didnt got much info about(reviews) about  [Google chart](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) API, has any one compared the pro's and cons of Jqplot and Google charts api ? Do i need to use GWT for using Google Charts API?

Comment: I don't know why it has been closed. I find it usefull.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Google api chart generates **swf file** (i.e. flash file) and jqplot draws chart on **canvas**(html5 element)
2. Both charting tools are easy to use
3. Most of the facilities (e.g zoom, mouseover effect, labels on chart, multiple scales on chart etc ) that are provided in google chart are also provided in jqplot
4. jqplot provides facility that when u resize your browser window jqplot automatically resize your chart but this is not in google chart

Comment: how many scales i can add to google chart and on jqplot?

Comment: on jqplot chart you can create up to 9 Y axes...

Comment: jqPlot does not provide easy way to animate charts (ie. on data update) Google does. Now Google chart is fully SVG & HTML5 based (with old IEs compatibility)

Comment: It looks like animating charts is available in jqPlot per your comment on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761088/how-to-animate-diagrams-with-jquery-and-jqplot-updating-data).

Comment: Google chart tools are not available offline, which means charting on intranets or offline web apps can't use it. jqPlot is available offline.